# Laravel 8 migrations primary key issue

Tags: migration, laravel-8, primary-key

Today I made new migration as many times before. The error it threw at me really surprised me.

**SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "migrations_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(148) already exists. (SQL: insert into "migrations" ("migration", "batch") values (2023_07_04_154574_history_tables, 8))**

The console looks like this:

```
Migrating: 2023_07_04_154574_history_tables
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "migrations_pkey"

DETAIL:  Key (id)=(148) already exists. (SQL: insert into "migrations" ("migration", "batch") values (2023_07_04_154574_history_tables, 8))

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
// If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
// message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
// lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new QueryException(
        $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    );
}
```

Does somebody know what it means?